# Remove all views in UIView hierarchy and jump to the first view

Tags: iphone, ipad, memory-management, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have an app which has few subviews added to superview using

```
 [self.view addSubview:subview.view];
```

All are different view controllers and have custom back buttons to come back to main/first view. Until now no issue.

At some of in the app I have to jump from screen/subview 4 to first view, where I recreate first view. (using initWithNibName and addSubview). This increases a memory of the app.

To solve this, I want to remove all subviews and come back to first view as it already exists but is not visible instead of creating first view again.

How to achieve this?

Please help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi @Mobility would [[self.view subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperView)] suffice?? Its from the top of my head so take it as sudo-code rather than the exact code syntax.

Comment: @bennythemink I want to remove all views from view hierarchy and not just the subviews on view. WIll this work for the same?

Comment: Hey @Mobility if you are using iOS5 you could loop through all the sub view controllers, remove them from their superview AND [subViewController removeFromParentViewController]. That should remove them from the display and hierarchy

Comment: My app support iOS 4.3 and higher. Any other way to achieve this?

Comment: mmm... maybe loop through the sub view controllers, removeFromSuperView for each sub view, and then set the controller = nil for ARC or nil & release it if using manual memory management making sure its not referenced anywhere else that may cause a crash. I think this is correct, my brain is fried at the moment after a late night, the community will let us know if I am incorrect :)

Comment: also as @Safecase mentioned in his answer place a conditional to check that you are not removing the view you want.

Answer (score 2):

**You can declare the tag value of particular view, and remove all the view according to your need :**

*for (UIView *subview in [self.view subviews])

{

if(view isKindOfClass:[UIView class])

{

```
 if (subview.tag == 101 || subview.tag == 102)
```

{

```
 [subview removeFromSuperview];
```

}

}

}*

there is a sample code below this line: in this code button 'btn' created by xib  and which call btnClicked method

---

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    myViewNew = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 40, 150, 150)];
    [myViewNew setTag:102];
    [myViewNew setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

    myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 40, 150, 150)];
    [myView setTag:101];
    [myView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

    btn1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [btn1 setFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 50, 50)];
    btn1.titleLabel.text = @"btn1";
    [myView addSubview:btn1];

    [btn1 addTarget:self action:@selector(btn11Pressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    btn2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [btn2 setFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 50, 50)];
    btn2.titleLabel.text = @"btn2";
    [myViewNew addSubview:btn2];

    [btn2 addTarget:self action:@selector(btn2Pressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


}

-(void)btn2Pressed
{
     for (UIView *subview in [self.view subviews])
     {
       if(view isKindOfClass:[UIView class])

       {

        if (subview.tag == 101 || subview.tag == 102) 
        {
            [subview removeFromSuperview];
        }
       }

      }
}

-(void) btn11Pressed:(id)sender
{
    [self.view addSubview:myViewNew];
}

-(IBAction)btnClicked:(id)sender
{
    [self.view addSubview:myView];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want remove all subview and come firstview:

```
  //here view where you want remove all sub views containing in view
  [[self.view subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperView)];
```

Do this to keep one subview on view:

```
    NSArray *allSubViews = [self.view subviews];
    for(int i= 0; [allSubViews count];i++)
    {
      if(i !=0)
      {
          UIView *view = [allSubViews objectAtIndex:i];
          [view removeFromSuperview];
      }
    }
```

Comment: I did this just now, this gives me list of subviews added on a view e.g. nab bar, button, uitableview. But I want all the screens in view hierarchy and remove all of them and jump back to home screen

Comment: instead of view use homescreen reference like NSArray *allSubViews = [homescreen subviews];